# While/For Loop won't loop. (C++)

Tags: c++, loops

I'm new to programming. But as I'm making a simple slot machine (it does not have prizes yet), i can't seem to make the loop loop, and give the player another try!
If i set the condition to 1, it loops fine, but not i have a simple ( i > 0 ) condition. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int slot1 (int low, int high)
{
    return rand() % ( high - low + 2 ) + low;
}

int slot2 (int low, int high)
{
    return rand() % ( high - low + 2 ) + low;
}

int slot3 (int low, int high)
{
    return rand() % ( high - low + 2 ) + low;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 100;
    cout << "\n\n       Welcome to the Slot Machine!\n\n";
    cout << "       You have " << i << " coins!\n\n";
    cout << "       Each spin costs 1 coin! Press ENTER to begin.\n\n";
"\n";

while ( i > 0 )
{
    cin.get();
    "\n";
    --i;
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    cout << "       | " << slot1( 1, 8);
    cout << " | " << slot2( 1, 8);
    cout << " | " << slot3( 1, 8) << " |\n";

    // if statements adding to int i, depending of the values of slot1, slot2 and slot3.

    if (i = 0 )
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `srand` *once* in your entire program.  Do not `srand` every iteration of your loop.  Also, your lines that are just `"\n";` don't do anything.  If you want a newline, you have to `cout << "\n";`

Comment: Why have you got three identical equations

Comment: What the statement `"\n";` is nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (i = 0 )
```

This should be `==`. The symbol `=` is for assignment, not equality comparison.

Although `i = 0` evaluates falsely so the inner `break` isn't executed, it doesn't matter because the very next thing that happens is `i > 0` fails and so your loop ends regardless. On the first iteration. Every time you run your program.

You also need to move that `srand` call out of the loop: you should have it *once* in your program, not *n* times.

Answer (score 0):

Still room for improvement here, but this might help you understand:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int slot (int low, int high)
{
    return rand() % ( high - low + 2 ) + low;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 100;
    cout << "\n\n       Welcome to the Slot Machine!\n\n";
    cout << "       You have " << i << " coins!\n\n";
    cout << "       Each spin costs 1 coin! Press ENTER to begin.\n\n\n";      
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    while ( i > 0 )
    {
        cin.get();
        cout<<"\n";       
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            cout << " | " << slot( 1, 8);
        }
        cout<<" |\n";
        --i;           
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you have decided to rewrite the entire program, you can leave out the `if (i == 0 )` block, as it is useless: if `i` is 0 the `while` will be interrupted in any case, there's no need to check twice.

Comment: nice inside loop there! thanks!

Comment: No problem. In this case the nested loop is not required, but it does serve to keep the code a little more concise. In any case, I hope this helps you understand how loops work.